# jQuery Post data not working

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-post

I am trying to post the values of checked boxes, but unable to do so. It first collects all the checked boxes in an array (`datas`-which is working fine upon testing it with `console.log(datas)`) and then sends them collectively. But I'm not able to post the data. I'm getting an empty array. Where I'm going wrong?

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    selected_users = request.POST.getlist('users[]')
    return HttpResponse(selected_users)
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var datas = new Array();
        var i = 0;

        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            datas[i] = $(this).val();
            i++;
        });   

        console.log(datas)   //works fine
        $.post("get_data/", {'users[]': datas}, function(data){
            alert(data);
        });   
    });    
})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'get_data/','apps.api.views.get_data', name = 'grabhalo_get_data'),
)
```

**Checkboxes**

```
{% for user in users %}
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="{{user.id}}" />{{user.name}}<br>    
{%endfor%}

    <form id="form" method="POST" action="#">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <input type="text" class="span8 search-query" placeholder="Type here..." name="chat">
       <input type="submit" value="Send" class = "btn btn-primary" id = "submit">
   </form>
```

Here are the parameters while viewing **console.log**

```
users[] 1
users[] 2
```

I'm guess there is some bug in views.py, though not sure. Kindly help me rectify the same.

Answer (score 0):

**1.  Missing prevent default**

replace:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
```

with:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
```

**2. Missing name for checkboxes**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="..."
```

Comment: Apology. I forgot to add the `name` parameter. I tried your solution, but it isnt working. Any more suggestions.

Comment: upon replacement with `e.preventDefault();` , it throws an error saying `403-Forbidden Error- CSRF Verification Failded`

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying could be achived easily with slight code rearranging

### Checkboxes

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="#">
    {% for user in users %}
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" name='users' value="{{user.id}}" />{{user.name}}<br>    
    {% endfor %}

    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="span8 search-query" placeholder="Type here..." name="chat">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class = "btn btn-primary" id = "submit">
</form>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        $.post("get_data/", $(this).serialize(), function(data){
            alert(data);
        });   
    });    
})
```

See [docs on `jQuery.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and especially note

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No
>   submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
>   using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the
>   serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from
>   checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox")
>   are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements
>   is not serialized.

### views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    selected_users = request.POST.getlist('users')
    return HttpResponse(selected_users)
```

Comment: Its not getting into the `request.POST` condition.

Comment: Any idea why it is not satisfying the condition?

Comment: `print(k)` prints nothing?

Comment: Well the keys are `csrfmiddlewaretoken` and `chats` , but not the `users`. Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Because my checkboxes are not inside the form, so its logical enough that `users` key is not available, but since I am posting it in jQuery using `users` variable, how can I get the `users` variable?